# How do I notate sharps in ABC notation?

Tags: notation, software, accidentals, musicxml, abc-notation

I'm trying to convert the dozenal representation of tau (=2*pi) to a series of notes. I was trying to use ABC notation, but I don't know how to indicate sharps or flats. I'd like to use a notation as simple as ABC, then convert to a MusicXML file that I can open and play back.

Here's a snippet of the sequence I'm trying to write in ABC notation: `F# D# E A E C# F# A F# G B F# D# F C# C G# B D G A C E D D# B A# D A# D A# A# D# G# C B D F`.

Comment: The musicality of the result will likely be disappointing: the fraction part is quite random.

Comment: @guidot: It works if you hack it about a lot https://youtu.be/3174T-3-59Q

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- Sharp - `^`
- Flat - `_`
- Natural - `=`

From [The abc music standard 2.1 (Dec 2011)](http://abcnotation.com/wiki/abc:standard:v2.1#accidentals)

> The symbols **^, = and _** are used (before a note) to notate **respectively a sharp, natural or flat**. Double sharps and flats are available with ^^ and __ respectively.

Comment: Thanks! I looked through the music standard before I asked, even did a search for "sharp", but I must have glossed over the Accidentals section.

Answer (score 12):

A simple google(*) finds the following tutorial:
http://www.lesession.co.uk/abc/abc_notation.htm#sharps

```
sharp: ^f
flat: _b
natural: =c
```

Note that the accidental precedes the note.

(*) When googling for information about ABC, it often helps to add the word "notation" to the search, to weed out false positives.